# How to Implement Timestamp in oracle?

Tags: oracle11g, timestamp

```
create table abc_test(
  id number,
  rv timestamp
);

insert into abc_test(id,rv) values (1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

Is there any better way to do it?

Can the timestamp be stored in the database in some binary format like "01x0000000000046565".

In Microsoft sql, this can easily be done as below :

```
create table xyz_test(id1 timestamp, name varchar(50))

insert into xyz_test (Name) values('person1')

select * from xyz_test
```

The above query will show some binary form for the timestamp column and "person1" in the name column

How to get the same result in the oracle?

Comment: What is wrong with this approach? What is you ultimate goal?

Comment: I want time stamp to be in binary form, just like in MS SQL

Comment: You should add the binary form comment as a part of the question as that is your goal.

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed stored in a binary format -- the tool that you are using translates it when it is retrieved.

Display of dates and timestamps is dependent on tool configuration, and on session settings etc.. You can read the timestamp in whatever format you like -- consult the documentation for To_Char(datetime).